# Fission Weapon Mechanism and Critical Mass

Tags: nuclear-physics, explosions, nuclear-engineering

[image: Little Boy]

In the image we see the interior design of the Little Boy atomic bomb dropped on Hiroshima. There are two cylinders composed of uranium, a hollow cylinder at the top which will slide down to merge with the cylinder at the bottom. Both of these cylinders are below the critical mass but their combined mass surpasses the critical mass causing it to explode.

So my question is: How do we define the merging of these cylinders because the fact that they are touching each other does not mean that they've actually became one material, maybe there's a single atom layer of air trapped between even if there's no air between there's no metallic bonds either. If this is the case then the merged situation is the same as the non merged situation thus they're still two separate objects which can't sustain fission.

Does the cylinders need to make metallic bonds with each other or not? Or do they bond with each other because of the heat generated by the conventional explosives?

Or is it just enough for them to make electrical contact for us to say that the combined cylinders have passed the critical mass? If this is the case will they explode if we just connect them together with an electrically conductive wire?

Comment: "The Demon Core", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core is instructive...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do we define the merging of these cylinders

Merging (like touching) isn't really the important bit.  The fuel is rearranged to form a supercritical geometry.  The Chernobyl reactor went critical with all the fuel separated into rods that didn't touch each other.

Each unit of uranium in the weapon has some amount of decay that produces neutrons.  These neutrons leave the fuel and have some chance of finding more fuel and initiating a fission event based on where the fissile material is and what is in the way.

In the weapon, the two cylinders are so far apart initially that most of the neutrons released fly away and do not reach the other to start additional reactions.

When the pieces are brought together, it is not the fact that they touch or anything, just that they are close enough for the neutrons to have an increased chance of encountering more material.  If the space between the two were filled with a neutron absorber, that would limit the reaction.  But a few mm of air would not be significant.

Although the common term is "critical mass", mass is only one portion of the equation.  Fuel composition, geometry, and interposing materials such as moderators and absorbers all determine criticality together.

Answer (score 2):

As the combined masses are largely supercritical, even the presence of an air film between the masses would not hinder the development of the chain reaction, would not hinder the diffusion and the multiplication of neutrons in the two media.

Answer (score 1):

The two bodies of uranium don't need to touch
each other. It is enough when the two bodies are separated
by a gap of air. Then a neutron emitted by a splitting
nucleus within one body can still pass over the gap
into the other body and hit a nucleus there,
and thus sustain the chain reaction.

Answer (score 1):

First let's understand what the term "critical" means in a fission process. We look at the time rate of fissions, i.e., fissions per nanosecond (or whatever time unit you want to choose, but for explosions, nanosecond is good):

1. Fissions per nanosecond is decreasing $\to$ sub-critical,  no self-sustaining chain reaction, no explosion
2. Fissions per nanosecond is constant $\to$ critical, self-sustaining chain reaction but no increase in power, no explosion
3. Fissions per nanosecond is increasing $\to$ super-critical, self-sustaining chain reaction with increase in power, possible explosion depending on power slope and containment time.

The criticality state of a mass of uranium depends on the mass of the uranium, the geometry of the uranium, and the neutron reflectivity/absorption of the material surrounding the uranium. The most efficient geometry is spherical. That requires the least mass to be critical. Surrounding the uranium with other materials may either reflect, absorb, or transmit neutrons, making the actual assembly more or less (super-)critical.

So, the ability of a mass of uranium to cause an explosion depends on several factors, the least of which would be a small air gap between two cylinders or hemispheres. Producing an explosion depends on assembling a *supercritical mass geometry* for a microsecond or more duration before the energy release pushes everything apart.

Comment: Oh, so the spherical geometry being the most efficient explains the implosion type bombs. Thanks!